# Java SOAP WS client code throws AxisFault while SOAP UI does'nt

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis, webservice-client

While consuming third party SOAP based webservices in Java (by generating web service client), AxisFault exception is thrown by generated proxy code due to special characters (#,&) present in SOAP response. It means, the service provider processes the request and sends back the response. Response could be seen in SOAP UI when tried for the same request.

> {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 180764; Character reference "&#

Above mentioned exception is thrown by apache axis SAX parser internally used by generated WS client.

Please help me in resolving this issue? Encoding type in generated code is UTF-8.

Thanks in advance!!

Also, noted in SOAP UI the xml response with special character is not formatted correctly. On validation the xml error is shown. This is not the case for the response without special character.

Comment: Can you add complete stacktrace and SOAP request for which which you are getting the exception?

Comment: The issue occurred because the generated client code (wsimport / axis) internally uses SAX-PARSER which fails to parse the response having special characters as it is an invalid xml. Possible solutions are either the service provider should enclose the response in CDATA (if the response structure is undefined in WSDL) / service should be consumed using direct http call.

Answer (score 0):

That means, you are generating your client code(stubs), by using Apache Axis. I think you are doing this in Eclipse(By creating a web service client using New wixard). Never do like that. Eclipse internallu uses Apache Axis by default. So you may face issues.
Try generate the client code by using 'WSIMPORT' tool, which comes with JDK1.6 and above.
You may use this link [WSIMPORT](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/)

Comment: As you said, I have generated code through eclipse plugin. Now, I tried generating code using WSIMPORT for SOAP1.2 biniding. Unfortunately the response is not retrieved by the generated code.

Comment: You are able to get the response from a SOAP UI, that means service works fine, your code is not working. Can you add your piece of code, how you are making SOAP call?